# Can I combine lattices (group) and Minkowski's Theorem with crystallography?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, physics, lattice-orders, crystallography

I am studying computer science and have an interest in material science. sadly I am only a layman in mathematics and physics. but I want to understand those better to be able to use them more freely and efficiently when thinking about problems and solutions for ideas I have.

At the moment I am trying to do something with sets in lattices in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that satisfy Minkowski's Theorem (symmetric to origin, convex and bounded). the idea I was thinking about was to use it for some kind of structural analysis of crystal structures.

I was asking myself if you could use this with something like dense sphere packing, but I can't connect the dots in my head. or maybe there simply are no dots to connect. therefore, it would really help me a lot if I could get feedback. please don't hold back.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice

Comment: @WillJagy thank you for the link. I will read it tomorrow. would it be OK to ask follow-up questions, or should I rather let you be?

Comment: well, read it first... I probably don't know the kind of thing you want,

Comment: I was planning on reading it first. maybe there will be no need for further questions. thank you for your help and all the best.